# Derive differential equations from given functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory

Define functions

$K(m) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-mx^2)(1-x^2)}} \,dx$

$E(m) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{1-mx^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2} }\ \,dx$

for $m \in ({0,1})$

Write the derivative $K'(m)$ and $E'(m)$ using $K(m)$ and $E(m)$ (derive differential equation for K and E)

There is also a hint in the exercise:

For $K'(m)$ consider $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}(y \sqrt{ \frac{1-y^2}{1-my^2}})$

After swapping the integral and derivative (with respect to m) I am able to find the value of the derivative (at least for function E) but have no idea how to express it as $K'(m)$ and $E'(m)$. Thank you for any help